# rsyslog is not discarding message as it should

Tags: logs, syslog, rsyslog

I have set up `rsyslog` to write messages from `local0.*` to a separate logfile, and then discard the messages. For some reason, the logs are going to *both* `/var/log/syslog`, and the new logfile.

I have put the config in `rsyslog.d/30-local0.conf`, which as far as I know, should come before the `50-default.conf`, and so the message should be discarded before hitting the standard rules and being written to syslog?

Comment: Try manually running `rsyslogd -c4 -d` and inspect the debugging output. `rsyslogd -c4 -d | grep rsyslog.d` should show you which files and the order they are included.

Comment: Your problem statement is incomplete - it needs the exact configuration you are testing.  Please [edit] your question to add a [mcve] of a configuration that fails, together with a message (e.g. using the `logger` command) that you test it with.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds correct so far, we may need more data (your actual config files).

Just to be sure, you should have this in `30-local0.conf`:

```
local0.* /var/log/local0.log
       & ~
```

Comment: sorry, yeah, that's what my file looks like. Well, the '& ~' isn't indented, but that doesnt matter right?

Comment: the config files are standard as far as i know from an ubuntu lucid install.

Comment: Indentation doesn't matter; it's only for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Given the date of your question and your distribution you might have been affected by a bug in rsyslog versions < 5.6.5, see [Message discarding does not work](http://bugzilla.adiscon.com/show_bug.cgi?id=217); the issue has been fixed as of rsyslog [version 5.6.5](http://www.rsyslog.com/changelog-for-5-6-5-v5-stable/).

Please note, that the default rsyslog package for Ubuntu Lucid is in fact version 4.2.0, but it is not unusual to update rsyslog via a [PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA) do gain current features (we've been affected by this issue due to rsyslog version 5.6.3 installed from a PPA indeed).

Answer (score 0):

On some versions, `& ~` (with a space in between) doesn't work, but `&~` (no space) does work. (After a restart of the service of course.)

On others still, `stop` might work instead. But it doesn't on Debian 7 / rsyslog 5.8.11.